# Windows fails to boot succesfully

Tags: windows-7

When I turn on my laptop it give me options to

- Start Windows normally
- Start in safe mode
- Start in safe mode with networking
- Start in safe mode with command prompt.

If I select start windows normally it starts loading windows but fails. If I choose an other option it looks like it downloading filed.

Comment: What do you mean with "looks like it downloading filed"?

Comment: You mention that you are out of your country. Is your internet connection secure? Sounds like someone may be trying to get in to your system. Are other people with Windows in the seminar having similar problems?

Comment: it start loading files if I select other options like start window with safe mode..I left it for more that 3hr and I find thelast file to be loaded is window system32 drivers classpnp.sys.No any changes to that point.bt if I select start window normally it seems like it also failed to start window since it write start window but nothing new

Comment: It's normal for Windows to display the list of files it's loading when you boot into safe mode - it's not downloading anything from the Internet, just loading from the hard drive, and it does not mean you're under attack. I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, though.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using a repair disk and attempt repairs and try doing a rollback. If that fails, your best bet will be to reinstall the OS files.